# php mysql select something and get columns from other tables

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I'm using prepared statements and I need to "select" other table, apart from these two, to get data but I get this:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\views\user\referral.php on line 16
```

If I add in SELECT table1.* , table.* , "theothertable.*"

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT friends.*, rc_usuario.* // or just *
    FROM friends
    INNER JOIN rc_usuario ON rc_usuario.id = friends.friendID
    WHERE friends.userID = ?");

$stmt->bind_param('s', $connectedUserID);
```

This is working fine, I get what i need, but I also need to get data from another table and I can't make other select because i need it all in a while to print all the data together.

The question is, can I SELECT something like that from 2 tables and also get data from other table/s?

Thank YOU!

EDIT: Add the new statement:

```
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT friends.*, members.*, account_type.*
    FROM friends
    INNER JOIN members ON members.id = friends.friendID
    INNER JOIN account_type ON account_type.name = members.acc_type
    WHERE friends.userID = ? AND members.acc_type = ?")) {

    $stmt->bind_param('is', $connectedUserID, $connectedAcc_type);
    $stmt->execute();
    } else echo $mysqli->error;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join more tables by using another `INNER JOIN`, like as follows;

```
INNER JOIN rc_usuario ON rc_usuario.id = friends.friendID
INNER JOIN rc_another ON rc_another.col = friends.coljoin
```

Just make sure you select all the columns you want in the joined table.

It might also help to run your prepare statement in an if, like this;

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ...")) { // ... where the rest of your query is
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $connectedUserID);
    $stmt->execute();
}
else {
    echo $mysqli->error;
}
```

which will give you an idea of any problems with the SQL syntax.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I added the if and else and is giving me this error: Not unique table/alias: 'members'
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_result() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\views\user\referral.php on line 25

Comment: Where you edited your question, don't say `FROM friends, members`, just say `FROM friends` as you then join members right afterwards. The second error is because there is no result because of the error in the SQL.

Comment: Ah yes, that's why error reporting is so useful! If this answer worked for you, you can accept it by clicking on the tick on the left.